# How to get newly created post id generated from backend API after dispatch createPost action to a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-thunk

I can't figure out how to get new post id after dispatch the post object to reducer through middleware thunk. If could get new post id, I want to redirect to new post page by history.push(`/${newPost_id}`). my code is:

backend controller:

```
export const addFilm = async (req, res) => {
    const film = req.body
    try {
        const newFilm = new Film(film)
        console.log(newFilm)
        await newFilm.save()
        res.status(201).json(newFilm)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({message: error.message})
    }
}
```

frontend event handleSubmit:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(addFilm(filmData))
        history.push(`/${newPost_id}`)//how to implement this?
      }
  }
```

actions:

Comment: @Pengin how do you expect that to work? If you have no ID to ask for how would the backend know which object to return. Instead the server should respond with the ID of the newly created object, specifically the `newFilm` should be enriched before returning it in `res.status(201).json(newFilm)`

Comment: why don't you make a state for the id and update the state inside the addFilm action?

Comment: and you can create a useEffect and check if the id exists and inside the if check write the  `history.push()` line

Comment: yes, you are right. I actually applied useEffect(), if id exists, then history.push(`/${id}`), but, after get into new post page, and at the page header, there is an addNewPost button, click it you can create another post, and it is under <Route path='/add'> , by clicking it, it always show last single post page.useEffect(() => {
        if(films.length === 1) {
            
            history.push(`/${films[0]._id}`)
        }
    }, [history, films])

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your backend returns a complete film object which has the `id` property added to it.

The redux-thunk middleware changes the behavior of `dispatch` such that it returns the value that was returned from your thunk.  You will want to design your `addFilm` thunk such that it dispatches the correct actions and also returns the `newFilm` that it got from the backend.

Then you can modify your handler like so:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newFilm = await dispatch(addFilm(filmData));
    history.push(`/${newFilm.id}`);
}
```

[Thunk Docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition)

Comment: Thanks for support, I read Thunk Docs, I didn't know thunk could return a value, it is absolutely the same as the returned value by inner async function. const result = await dispatch(action()), it solves my question.